# how to add regex patterns to input based on selection of dropdowns in angular material

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, angular-material

I am using angular material and based on selection of dropdown there must be change in patterns to the input field. i have done in this way, but I am unable to get error message in HTML and also i have to reduce lines of code, instead of writing if else condition, how can it be dynamically called.

TS:

```js
onDropDownChange(event: any) {
    if (event == 1) {
        this.form.get('inputValue').reset();
        this.form
            .get('inputValue')
            .setValidators(Validators.pattern('[0-9]{12}'));
    } else if (event == 2) {
        this.form.get('inputValue').reset();
        this.form
            .get('inputValue')
            .setValidators(Validators.pattern('[A-Z]{2}d{7}'));
    } else if (event == 3) {
        this.form.get('inputValue').reset();
        this.form
            .get('inputValue')
            .setValidators(Validators.pattern('d{6}[A-Z]{3}'));
    }
}
```

HTML:

```html
<mat-form-field style="width:80%;" class="select-input-field">
    <mat-select [(value)]="selected" placeholder="Inspection Type" (selectionChange)="onDropDownChange($event)">
        <mat-option [value]="">None</mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let inspectionType of inspectionTypes" [value]="inspectionType.inspection_type_id">{{inspectionType.description}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<form [formGroup]="form">
    <input type="text" formControlName="inputValue" placeHolder="predicatePlaceHolder" >
    {{form.get('inputValue').hasError('pattern')}}
    <mat-error class="alert-danger" *ngIf="form.get('inputValue').hasError('pattern')" >
    Invalid User</mat-error>
</form>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-dropdown-pdsytq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce an array holding all your pattern strings, ordered as you already did, something like:

`validators = [ first_pattern_string,second_pattern_string, third_pattern_string];`

Then change your event handler to something like:

```
onDropDownChange(event: number, inputValue = this.form.get('inputValue')) {
   inputValue.reset();
   inputValue.clearValidators();
   inputValue.setValidators(Validators.pattern(this.validators[event-1]));
   inputValue.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

**EDIT:**

Now that you've added a demo, I see you're not returning a number from event, but a property of the object. So you have to find its object's index and use it to get an item from validators array.

Also, you need to create a real RegExp, not just strings.

Here's a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-dropdown-jlhc1h

So: replace regExp I've put there and you're good to go.

Comment: Although, be sure that you actually get a number from event, otherwise change its type.

Comment: thanks for response, what if i have string instead of number

Comment: i have added demo, please check and correct me

Comment: Is it working if you put `[+event-1]` instead of `[event-1]`?

Comment: i will check but for pattern it is not showing error

Comment: any help i have created demo as well

Comment: Check an edited answer.

Comment: thanks for respose @Misha, my concern is that i dont have only 3 objects in array, i have 10 objects among those 10 objects, these objects may have any index in it, so accordingly it has to be checked

Comment: hi Misha, one help, here based on selection of dropdown i am setting the pattern, but now how can i make input to accept only numbers and not alpha, few dropdowns may have hypen, and one dropdown has 2 alpha characters, so in this situation, how can this be handled?

Comment: You mean disallowing a user to input restricted characters, or allowing him to input - but treating it as invalid input?

Comment: example, i have only 7 digit numbers, so this must allow numbers only, with no alphabets and special characters, in user input itself that has to be restricted